# Laravel Eloquent, how to select users of certain type from many to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am a extreme beginner at Laravel. Looked at the documentation on the website and have managed to create a many to many relation of classes and users.

Tables structure

Users 
Classes
Users_Classes

Users table

users_id 
users_type 'student','teacher'

Classes table

class_id
class_name

Uses_Classes table

user_id
class_id

Classroom Model

```
<?php       
public function getStudents() {
       return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'cla_use_relationship', 'cla_class_id', 'use_users_id');
        }

?>
```

Admin Controller

```
 $students = Classroom::find(1)->getStudents;
```

So the students variable is populated with users where class id = 1. What I need though is all the users of type student. So far its getting all users. I tried doing a where function but no users were returned.

Is there any good resources on beginners understanding laravel, especially the Eloquent side of it, understanding what functions work with what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your `belongsTo` you can chain a `where` clause to restrict it to just students, something like

```
public function getStudents() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'cla_use_relationship', 'cla_class_id', 'use_users_id')
        ->where('users_type', 'student');
}
```

For getting into the basics of laravel, I'd recommend checking out the resources on the main docs page: http://laravel.com/docs#additional-resources

`Code Bright` would probably be the best for a beginner, then work your way up from there.

Comment: Thank you that worked fine. I will have a look at Code Bright and see what they have.